After updating PHP version from 8.2.6 to 8.2.20, I get error about an invalid attribute on a PDO object
I needed to update the PHP version from 8.2.6 to 8.2.20 for the security update.
I am using IIS 10. The only thing I did was to replace the php directory at C:/php with the new version of php.
I also copied the php.ini file so it would be the same, and I copied the SQL Server PDO extension - php_pdo_sqlsrv_82_nts_x64.dll that was inside C:/php/ext to the new php directory.
I then restarted the application pool and the website, cleared the Laravel app cache.
But now I get the following error:
SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: An invalid attribute was designated on the PDO object.

What could be the issue?

https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql/issues You might get started from GitHub.

thanks, I think I may have found the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76818310/laravel-10-stopped-working-with-sql-server-database/76912232#76912232. Tomorrow I will try and update if it worked

@LexLi update: Indeed there is a bug with the SQL Server PDO version I had that caused it to not work with Laravel and php 8.2.6. After I downloaded the latest PDO extension from Microsoft, it worked again. At first I wasn't sure it would do anything becuase their size is the same - 318KB, so the fix must've been really minor

I found the issue: There was a bug fixe in the PDO extension for SQL Server that causes PHP version prior to 8.2.9 to break (at least when using Laravel).
For more information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76818310/laravel-10-stopped-working-with-sql-server-database/76912232#76912232
So I downloaded the latest SQL Server drivers from Microsoft for my version (8.2 pdo nts in my case), and it worked!
